# Undefined variable: row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I got a function that requests some information from my database, puts it in an array and returns it. The sql-statement is correct.

When the current date is not found in the database, I would like to display an error on my website.
The error message, is added also in the return array.

First I check if the corresponding date exists in the database with a COUNT, if the count == 1, I get all the data from the database with another statement. If the count != 1, I put together an array hard code.

When a date is found in the database that is the same as the given parameter, the script works like a charm, but when I change the date in the database, the I get the following error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: row in
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/models/funcs.php on line 1257

Line 1252-1257:

```
while($stmt->fetch())
            {
                $row[] = array('id' => $id, 'datum' => $datum, 'mac' => $mac, 'ipad' => $ipad, 'iphone' => $iphone, 'imember' => $imember, 'applecare' => $applecare, 'verkoop_ochtend' => $verkoop_ochtend, 'verkoop_middag' => $verkoop_middag, 'verkoop_avond' => $verkoop_avond, 'vracht_ochtend' => $vracht_ochtend, 'vracht_middag' => $vracht_middag, 'vracht_avond' => $vracht_avond, 'service_ochtend' => $service_ochtend, 'service_middag' => $service_middag, 'service_avond' => $service_avond, 'werkzaamheden' => $werkzaamheden, 'error' => '');
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $data = $row;
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance!

The complete function:

```
function get_current_planning($date)
{
    GLOBAL $mysqli, $db_table_prefix;
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COUNT(datum) FROM " . $db_table_prefix . "planning WHERE datum = '" . $date . "'");
    $result = $stmt->execute();
print_r($result);
var_dump($result);

    if($result == 1)
    {
        $stmt->prepare("SELECT
                                        *
                                        FROM " . $db_table_prefix . "planning
                                        WHERE datum = '" . $date . "'");
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $datum, $mac, $ipad, $iphone, $imember, $applecare, $verkoop_ochtend, $verkoop_middag, $verkoop_avond, $vracht_ochtend, $vracht_middag, $vracht_avond, $service_ochtend, $service_middag, $service_avond, $werkzaamheden);
        while($stmt->fetch())
            {
                $row[] = array('id' => $id, 'datum' => $datum, 'mac' => $mac, 'ipad' => $ipad, 'iphone' => $iphone, 'imember' => $imember, 'applecare' => $applecare, 'verkoop_ochtend' => $verkoop_ochtend, 'verkoop_middag' => $verkoop_middag, 'verkoop_avond' => $verkoop_avond, 'vracht_ochtend' => $vracht_ochtend, 'vracht_middag' => $vracht_middag, 'vracht_avond' => $vracht_avond, 'service_ochtend' => $service_ochtend, 'service_middag' => $service_middag, 'service_avond' => $service_avond, 'werkzaamheden' => $werkzaamheden, 'error' => '');
            }
            $stmt->close();
            $data = $row;
    }
    else
    {
        $row[] = array('id' => '', 'datum' => '', 'mac' => '', 'ipad' => '', 'iphone' => '', 'imember' => '', 'applecare' => '', 'verkoop_ochtend' => '', 'verkoop_middag' => '', 'verkoop_avond' => '', 'vracht_ochtend' => '', 'vracht_middag' => '', 'vracht_avond' => '', 'service_ochtend' => '', 'service_middag' => '', 'service_avond' => '', 'werkzaamheden' => '', 'error' => 'Er is geen planning gevonden voor de huidige datum!');
        $stmt->close();
        $data = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

> print_r($result) returns 1
>
> var_dump($result) returns bool(true)

Comment: What if there are no rows? Since you're not defining `$rows` before your loop it would never exist (and be an *undefined* variable!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not `fetch()`ing the the result of your `SELECT COUNT()...`  query.  It looks to me like your `while(...fetch())` loop in your second query is sometimes running zero times. This will result in the code beginning `$row[] =` getting run no times, which in turn will result in `$row` turning up undefined after the `while(...fetch())` loop.

At any rate it's a bit wasteful to count the rows and then fetch them, with two consecutive queries. You may want to skip the `SELECT COUNT` query entirely. Instead, do this sort of thing:

```
$row = Array();
while($stmt->fetch()) {
    $row[] = array('id' => $id, 'datum' => $datum, 'mac' => $mac, 'ipad' => $ipad, 'iphone' => $iphone, 'imember' => $imember, 'applecare' => $applecare, 'verkoop_ochtend' => $verkoop_ochtend, 'verkoop_middag' => $verkoop_middag, 'verkoop_avond' => $verkoop_avond, 'vracht_ochtend' => $vracht_ochtend, 'vracht_middag' => $vracht_middag, 'vracht_avond' => $vracht_avond, 'service_ochtend' => $service_ochtend, 'service_middag' => $service_middag, 'service_avond' => $service_avond, 'werkzaamheden' => $werkzaamheden, 'error' => '');
}
$stmt->close();
if (0 == count($row)) {
     /* deal with the no matching rows case */
}
$data = $row;
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you haven't defined a variable `$row`. You need a `$row=Array();` before you can start treating `$row` as an array.

Comment: This is not completely true. You can write `$row[] = 'X'` to add a value to the array and the array will be defined if it wasn't yet. However, if the query returns no rows, the `while` loop has no iterations, and `$row` won't be defined. In that case `$data = $row;` will fail. Your solution will solve that problem, and it's often a good idea to initialize variables like this, for clarity and for unexpected behaviour like this.

Comment: @GolezTrol yes, it will be defined, but PHP will "notice" you about this. It is always recommended to declare all your variables. Recommended reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: @nikoskip I don't think that's the case for the shorthand array notation. Which is supported by the notice occurring on line `$data = $row;` (= line 1257). See also, the chapter "Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax" on the [PHP documentation about arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). ("Creating" kinda gives it away). Nevertheless, I completely agree with you about initializing variables.